# Independent research in statistics

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher, statistics

Is it possible to do independent reserach in statistics? If i do something what is the way to verify my work?

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. The "way to verify" your work (whatever you mean exactly) is the same like for non-independent research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "independent" you mean "not affiliated to a research institute", then: Yes, of course you can conduct research in statistics.

[Here](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/scholar/list?q=author.affiliation.name:(%22independent%20scholar%22)%20OR%20author.affiliation.name:(%22independent%20researcher%22)&p=0&n=10&s=date_published&d=%2B&f=false&e=false&l=en&authorField=author&dateFilterField=publishedYear&orderBy=%2Bdate_published&presentation=false&preview=true&stemmed=true&useAuthorId=false&subject.must=Statistics%20and%20Probability&subject.must=Statistics,%20Probability%20and%20Uncertainty&subject.must=Statistical%20and%20Nonlinear%20Physics&subject.must=Computational%20Mathematics) is a list of 74 scholarly works (as of Dec 2021) in the field of `Statistics and Probability`, `Statistics, Probability and Uncertainty`, `Statistical and Nonlinear Physics`, or `Computational Mathematics` published by at least one (co-)author whose affiliation was either `independent scholar` or `independent researcher`.

You can have your work "verified" by having it peer-reviewed. That is, submit your manuscript to any scholarly journal in the field of statistics. For instance, [Web of Science offers a list of journals](https://mjl.clarivate.com/search-results) - just filter it by the category `STATISTICS & PROBABILITY`. Pick your journal and read the author guidelines carefully (and read other papers published in that journal) before you do submit your manuscript. Good luck.

Comment: Independent researchers might not have easy access to Web of Science.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, that's true, which is why I merely linked to its (publicly accessible, freely browsable) Master Journal List.